# How to send username and password to node.js server running on Bluemix?

Tags: android, node.js, ibm-cloud

I am creating an Android app, that is deployed in Bluemix.  I need to send  username and password to Node.js running on Bluemix from my Android app.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do this?

Comment: Have you considered using Bluemix single-sign-on (SSO) service?

Comment: No, am using SQLDB service

Comment: I meant to use SSO service so you don't have to worry about doing your own authentication. Can you elaborate on how SQLDB service fits into this? Are you trying to send the SQLDB username and credential for your app to access your database?

Comment: Am storing username and password details in SQLDB Database.

Comment: So are you just trying to interact with a SQLDB from Node?

Comment: Yes, Am trying to interact with SQLDB from node

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for code to communicate between your Android app and your Node.js application? I would look into making a [HTTP POST from your android](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-login-screen-using-httpclient.html?m=1) app and sending the credentials in the post body. When dealing with passwords it's important to follow security protocols (SSL, password hashing, etc)

Comment: yeah i tried using AsynTask method but am getting errors....
that question is posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29936816/fatal-exception-asynctask-1-in-android-app-while-sending-username-and-passwo?noredirect=1#comment47995388_29936816